# Django models filter by the human-readable value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

Is possible to filter models by the human-readable value?

```
#models.py
class World(models.Model):
    COUNTRY_CHOICES = (('SP', 'Spain'), ('FR', 'France'))
    country=models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, default=None)
    province=models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None)

#managers.py
def get_provinces(self):
    provinces = self.filter(country='SP')
    return provinces
```

This returns the provinces whose country is Spain, but how can I do the same just filtering using 'Spain' instead of 'SP'?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.  Country names are not stored anywhere in the DB. So you have to get the country value from the display name and filter by it:

```
countries = dict((v, k) for k, v in World.COUNTRY_CHOICES)
provinces = self.filter(country=countries['Spain'])
```